# Why is Don't Starve Together laggy?

Tags: dont-starve-together

I am playing with my friend who is 2 miles away from where I am.

Both of our connection is over 20mbps according to [Internet Speed Test](http://www.speedtest.net/). We have 24mbps net connection(2mbps upload) and we have closed almost any other program which consumes the internet.

It says good host in the game(when you press tab) and the ping is around 30-40.

But for some reason the person who is not hosting has a very laggy play. We each tried hosting and each time we had lag issues.

My friends computer is Lenovo Yoga 2, i5, Windows 8, 8gb ram.

Mine is a desktop, 32gb ram, i7-3930K, win8, nvidia geforce gtx 760 graphics card

So I don't know what the problem is. Is the game buggy? I checked out all the forums and everyone seems to be playing fine. So what then?

Comment: A high price doesn't mean it's good for gaming. ANd it doesn't tell us anything about the system.

Comment: Fixed it, anything else I should add?

Comment: I'm assuming your 20mbs speed is your download speed. What is both of your upload speed? I reach about 20mbs download as well, but my upload is ~1mbps, which makes me an awful host.

Comment: Good point :O, mine is 2mbps , how much upload speed can make the game go smooth?

Comment: Do you legally own The Game in steam knk?

Comment: Yes both of us own the game legally in steam

Comment: Can you add me in steam? I have a server in netherlands which has 1000mbps upload and download, I'll Host from it and you can try to play? (to check if it is about you hosting or you playing) my steam link is in my profile

Comment: @ardaozkal Ive added you, and will be online for the next 8 hours message me anytime

Comment: Network speed and ping and completely different: a connection with good speed can have bad ping and vice versa. Test your ping, not your speed.

Answer (score 5):

There are [a lot](http://steamcommunity.com/app/322330/discussions/search/?q=lag) of posts complaining about the lag in the game, so you are not alone.  From the sound of it, it's definitely a bug; given that the game is still in beta, hopefully the developer's will fix it before the game is released.

Some users have reported successful elimination of lag by [running a dedicated sever](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Don%E2%80%99t_Starve_Together_Dedicated_Servers).

If that's not an option, I've only found [one workaround](http://steamcommunity.com/app/322330/discussions/0/616199347859815748/), but it's not a good one.  The linked poster noticed that [the more the host explores, the laggier it gets for everyone else](http://steamcommunity.com/app/322330/discussions/0/616199347859815748/#c616199736994059330).  So, the workaround is for the host to not explore very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you can open a port, consider using a dedicated server on your pc.

As of our last test together, I think that the server doesn't run on our pc but on Steam Servers etc.

So if you try to use a dedicated server, it might and probably will be faster.

Please see [this link](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Don%E2%80%99t_Starve_Together_Dedicated_Servers#Installing) to see how you can install it.

Answer (score -1):

One thing is to have lag and another to have low FPS, given your specs I'd say it's a lag issue, however you might want to measure your fps, just in case.

Now about the lag, you may have a great connection and still have lag issues. Lag spikes may arise if there's something else taking over the connection. A download for example, would take most of the bandwidth and interfere with the game.

Note that this download might or might not have been started by you. There might be another person on the network downloading something or a program might be updating itself.

You can use programs such as [Net Limiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/) to monitor your computer network traffic an find possible leaks.